# How to use Couchbase Java Client in a Dropwizard Project?

Tags: java, jackson, couchbase, dropwizard

I've been looking at the [couchbase-java-client](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client) project and wondering whether it's possible to use it inside of a [dropwizard](http://dropwizard.io/) project.

It seems like it'd be a natural fit, because couchbase is basically a JSON database, but the java client doesn't seem to be compatible with Jackson. As far as I can tell, the couchbase client library includes [its own internal implementation of a JSON library](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/tree/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/java/document/json) that's incompatible with all the other java JSON libs out there, which is really weird.

I found a [JacksonTransformers](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/java/transcoder/JacksonTransformers.java) class that looked promising at first. But upon closer inspection, the library is using a shaded version of Jackson (with a rewritten package of `com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.core`).

Anyhow, since dropwizard uses Jackson and Jersey for marshalling JSON documents through the REST API, what's the least-friction way of using the couchbase-java-client library? Is it even possible in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible to use Couchbase with Dropwizard. The client SDK provides JSON manipulation objects for the developer's convenience but it also allows for delegating JSON processing to a library like Jackson or GSON.
Take a look at the `RawJsonDocument` class [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/sdks/java-2.2/documents-basics.html#documents-basics__jsonraw).
Basically, you can use a Stringified JSON (coming out of any framework) to create one of those objects and the client SDK will understand it as a JSON document for any operation i.e.:

```
String content = "{\"hello\": \"couchbase\", \"active\": true}";
bucket.upsert(RawJsonDocument.create("rawJsonDoc", content));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to make this work.

1. Client requests to dw server for Resource Person.
2. DW server requests to couchebase, gets a Pojo back representing Person or JSON representing person.
3. If it's JSON, create a POJO with Jackson annotations in DW and return that to client
4. If it's a special couchebase pojo, map that to a Jackson pojo and return to to client

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on [@CamiloCrespo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34306338/3405171) answer:

```
public static Document<String> toDocument(String id, Object value,
        ObjectMapper mapper) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return RawJsonDocument.create(id, mapper.writeValueAsString(value));
}
```

Keep in mind, that you can't use a simply maper, like `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()`, with `Dropwizard`.

You can get it from `Environment#getObjectMapper()` in the `Application#run()` method, or use `Jackson.newObjectMapper()` for tests.

An example of using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson.newObjectMapper();
User user = User.createByLoginAndName("login", "name");
bucket.insert(toDocument("123", user, mapper));
```